# Is it possible to use a IOS emulator device in Android studio on a MAC?

Tags: ios, xcode, android-studio, flutter

Someone help me find a solution! The main reason I can't download Xcode and run an ios emulator is the fact that I dont have an upgraded version of MAC OS Catalina or even Mojave.

So the problem arises here due to the fact that I want to write dart code on Mac and I downloaded Android Studio on my Mac and then another potential problem arisen when I didn't have an Android phone to run an Android emulator.

So I was asking that if there is any possible way to run an IOS simulator in Android Studio on a MAC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are talking about run your Android Studio's project into an iOS virtual device, no it isn't possible.